# Let $k \geq 3 .$ Show that there exists a graph on $n$ vertices with $\Omega\left(n^{1+\frac{1}{k-1}}\right)$ many edges and no cycle of length $k$.

Tags: solution-verification, random-graphs, extremal-combinatorics, probabilistic-method, extremal-graph-theory

> Let $k \geq 3 .$ Show that there exists a graph on $n$ vertices with $\Omega\left(n^{1+\frac{1}{k-1}}\right)$ many edges and no cycle of length $k$.

I’d like to ask some questions about the following attempt, which is based on another, similar proof that I’ve read.

The idea is to consider a random graph on $n$ vertices. Normally, I’d try to make the expected number of cycles of length $k$ to be less than $1$, by choosing an appropriate edge probability. But in this case that would also lead to small expected number of edges (which we don’t like). So instead I’d choose a bigger $p$ (to be determined), allowing for some cycles of length $k$ to exist (say, about $n/2$ $k$-cycles) and also to get roughly $n^{1+\frac{1}{k-1}}$ edges. We then delete one vertex from each cycle, resulting in a $k$-cycle-free graph with vertex set of size of order $n$, and edge set of size of order  $n^{1+\frac{1}{k-1}}$.

> In particular, I choose $p = n^{\frac{1}{k+1} - 1}$. In $K_n$, the number of cycles of length $k$ is $\frac{n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)}{2k} \leq \frac{n^k}{2k}$. Letting $X$ be the random variable counting the number of cycles of length $k$ in $G \sim G(n,p)$, we then have:
> $$\mathbb{E}[X]= (np)^k \leq n^{\frac{k}{k+1}}$$
> By Markov’s inequality, we have:
> $$\mathbb{P}(X \geq n/2) \leq \frac{2\mathbb{E}[X]}{n} \leq 2 n^{\frac{k}{k+1} - 1} \to 0$$
> So with positive probability, there exists a class of graphs $G’$ on $n$ vertices with less than $n/2$ cycles of length $k$. In each of those graphs, deleting a vertex from each of those cycles, we obtain a class of graphs $\tilde{G}$ with at least $n/2$ vertices and no cycles of length $k$.
>
> Now the expected number of edges of those $\tilde{G}$ is ${{n/2} \choose 2}p \sim n^{1 + \frac{1}{k+1}}$, so there must exist a graph $G^\ast$ amongst those $\tilde{G}$ with that many edges. In particular, this implies $e(G^\ast) = \Omega\left(n^{1 + \frac{1}{k-1}}\right)$.

My questions are:

1. I toyed with different choices of $p$ for a bit, but couldn’t come up with a value that gives me exactly $\Omega\left(n^{1+\frac{1}{k-1}}\right)$ edges, but got $n^{1 + \frac{1}{k+1}}$ instead. I assume this is still ok?
2. As mentioned above, when deleting vertices, we must take care so that the remaining number of vertices is still of order $n$. This is represented in the expression $\mathbb{P}(X \geq n/2)$, which I must admit I lifted straight from the model proof. Would some value other than $n/2$ also work here, as long as it’s linear in $n$?

Answer (score 1):

First, to answer the questions you actually asked:

- No, $n^{1 + \frac1{k+1}}$ is not good enough if you're aiming for $n^{1 + \frac1{k-1}}$. For example, when $k=3$, you are aiming for $n^{3/2}$ and only getting $n^{5/4}$.
- Yes, any expression linear in $n$ would work equally well.

However, I don't understand why you're deleting a vertex from every cycle. Instead, you could delete an *edge* from every cycle. This will work better, because you have way more edges to delete than vertices, so you can allow a higher $p$.

In $G(n,p)$, the expected number of edges is $\binom n2 p$, and the expected number of $k$-cycles is at most $\frac{(np)^k}{2k}$. So after we delete an edge from every cycle, the expected number of edges left is at least $\binom n2 p - \frac{(np)^k}{2k}$. (We might end up deleting the same edge many times, but this can only help us!)

Now try $p = n^{\frac1{k-1} - 1}$. Then $\binom n2 p$ is roughly $\frac12 n^{1+\frac1{k-1}}$, while $\frac{(np)^k}{2k} = \frac1{2k} n^{1 + \frac1{k-1}}$, so you're still left with $\Omega(n^{1 + \frac1{k-1}})$ edges in expectation. Therefore there must be an outcome in which we get at least this many edges.